# Differentiating functions of multiples of dependant variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f \left( \frac{a(x)}{b(x)} \right)$ then what is $\frac{df}{dx}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x}$? How did you come to this answer? I'm guessing it's some kind of combination between the chain rule and quotient rule but I can't seem to get it to make sense in my head...

Comment: Why the tag [*multi*variable-calculus]? The only independent variable I see here is $x$...

Comment: My mistake - I can't seem to figure out how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}$ then $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{d f}{d X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial a}\frac{da}{dx}+\frac{df}{dX}\frac{\partial X}{\partial b}\frac{db}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx}\left( \frac{1}{b(x)} \frac{da}{dx} - \frac{a(x)}{b(x)^2} \frac{db}{dx} \right)$